# Why does my Android app's view only update under a specific circumstance?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout

I am working on an Android app that is behaving oddly. One of the first things this app does upon start up, is to start a listening thread that listens to a "server" app, on the same device, to get data. Once this data is received by the listening thread, I use it to update the main view. This, however only works if my app is started after the server app.

First a few details. My app and the server app are on the same device. They communicate with each other via UDP (the server app is a port of a Windows application). My app uses fragments, but the view I want to update is not within a fragment. Now some code.

**content_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_image_id"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- fragment code here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Listener myListener = new Listener(this);
        Thread listenerThread = new Thread(myListener);
        listenerThread.setName("My Listener Thread");
        listenerThread.start();
    }
}
```

**Listener.java**

```
public class Listener implements Runnable {
    public Listener (Activity mainActivity) {this.mainActivity = mainActivity;}
    private Activity mainActivity;
    private ImageView myImageView;
    private NewData newData;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            // Here is where my app gets the data from the server via UDP.
            // This always works, I am always getting the correct data.
            myImageView = (ImageView) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.my_image_id);
            mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    if(newData == 1){
                        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image_01);
                    } else if(newData == 2){
                        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image_02);
                    } else {
                        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error_image);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, if I start my app after the server app, then this all works perfectly. The images always changes when the new data changes. However, if I start my app before the server app, or if I restart the server app while my app is still running, then the images never changes, even though I am still getting the correct data from the server app.

What can I do to make sure the view can update at any time?

**EDIT:** I moved where I get the view to outside of the while loop (as a test) and now the code doesn't work at all.

Comment: That while loop is killing kittens.

Comment: If you have a better solution, I would love to hear it. (I'm being serious, not sarcastic.)

Comment: So wheres the communication code?  You could have the server app launch a broadcast when its started that your app listens for and kicks off a new connection at that point.

Comment: You should not be changing the ImageView resource (or anything else in the UI for that matter) from a background thread. You need to either A) use a Handler to comminucate the new data back to the main thread and change the UI from there. Or B) read up on AsyncTask and start using that rather than Thread/Handler. Also you should call findViewById() as few times as is possible. In your case you are calling it everytime through the loop. You should instead call it once and keep a reference to the View that it returns.

Comment: @FoamyGuy The method I am using "works", and it seemed like the cleanest way to do it. I cannot make the thread an AsyncTask, and Handlers looked too complex.

Comment: As @FoamyGuy says. You should read up some more. This code is going to cause problems sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Emmanuel I'm not sure how it can cause problems. First, all I am doing is updating a single image. There is no other code like this anywhere. Second, why is what I'm doing such a bad idea? I am new to Android development, so if you could point me to a reason this is bad, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Reasons why it is bad: 1. I am pretty sure you are leaking your `Activity`. 2. you basically have an infinite loop that is running on a `Thread` that has the same priority as the UI `Thread`. 3. You are posting to the UI `Thread` on every iteration of your loop. 4. `findViewById()` is being called on every iteration and it is an expensive operation.

Comment: I edited my post. When I moved the findViewById() outside of the while loop, the code doesn't work at all; not even if I start the server app first. I don't see how "posting to the UI Thread" on every iteration is bad.

Comment: That is why you should read up a bit more as to why it is bad. The code above as it is posted does not compile.

Comment: @Emmanuel The code does not compile, it is a sampling of the relevant code within my full codebase. I assure you that what I have does compile, and does [sometimes] update the image in the main view.

Comment: @Brian the method you are using clearly does not "works" though otherwise you wouldn't be here asking why it's not working properly. We are trying to point you in the right direction. If you are unwilling to go in that direction there really isn't much else that we can do.

Comment: @FoamyGuy from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html - "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)" The operation I am running in my thread is a very long-running operation that runs as long as my app does. I do not believe AsyncTask is the best for my purposes.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I read up on Handlers and implemented it in my code. It works well, thank you. I'm not sure if I implemented it correctly, but it appears to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try. apparently your code is working alright, if the thread starts after the activity is been initialized, i don't really know how your server app works so i tried to mimic something like this.

```
public class TestThreadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button restart_Button;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_thread);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_custom_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        restart_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TestThreadActivity_restart_button);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.TestThreadActivity_imageView);

        final Listener myListener = new Listener(this);

        restart_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.piccolo);
                final Thread listenerThread = new Thread(myListener);
                listenerThread.setName("My Listener Thread");
                listenerThread.start();

            }
        });

    }

    public class Listener implements Runnable {
        public Listener (Activity mainActivity) {this.mainActivity = mainActivity;}
        private Activity mainActivity;
        private ImageView myImageView;
        int newData = 0;

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                // Here is where my app gets the data from the server via UDP.
                // This always works, I am always getting the correct data.

                newData = (new Random()).nextInt(3);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                myImageView = (ImageView) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.TestThreadActivity_imageView);
                mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        System.out.println("newData: "+newData);
                        if(newData == 1){
                            myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gohan);
                        } else if(newData == 2){
                            myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.goku);
                        } else {
                            myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.piccolo);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> activity_test_thread.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="activities.list.first.TestThreadActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/my_custom_toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/TestThreadActivity_restart_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Start"
                android:contentDescription="this will restart the thread"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TestThreadActivity_imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gohan" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Output
>   [image]